# React component does not render correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working with React Native + TypeScript. I'm creating a custom button for reusability, and I'm using UI libraries for CSS styles. In addition to common CSS styles, I'm also using dynamic styles for the component that can be changed via props. I have the following problem:

When I access localhost, I see the button rendered, but the dynamic styles (only the dynamic ones) are not applied. If I go to Visual Studio Code and save (Ctrl + S) the dynamic styles, they apply, but if I refresh the page (F5), the styles disappear, and I have to save again for them to appear. Can someone help me with this?

Here's the code. First, I use a file called CustomImageButton.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ConfigCustomImageButton from 
"./ConfigCustomImageButton";

const CustomImageButton: React.FC = () => {
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  // Logic to handle the button click
  alert("Button clicked");
};

const buttomConfiguration = {
  buttonProps: {
  buttonText: "Button",
  showText: true,
  imageSvg: "",
  showImage: true,
  imagePosition: "right" as "left" | "right",
  svgData: {
    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    fill: "currentColor", //change color
    viewBox: "0 0 16 16",
    path: "M6.95.435c.58-.58 1.52-.58 2.1 0l6.515 
    6.516c.58.58.58 
    1.519 0 2.098L9.05 15.565c-.58.58-1.519.58-2.098 0L.435 
    9.05a1.482 1.482 0 0 1 0-2.098L6.95.435Zm1.385 6.547.8 
    1.386a.25.25 0 0 0 .451-.039l1.06-2.882a.25.25 0 0 
    0-.192-.333l-3.026-.523a.25.25 0 0 0-.26.371l.667 
    1.154-.621.373A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 6 8.632V11h1V8.632a1.5 1.5 0 0 
    1 
    .728-1.286l.607-.364Z",
  },
  //styles dynamics
  customStyles: {
    titleColor: '',
    titleFont: 'Arial',
    colorButton: '',
    borderRadius: '',
    imageHover: '',
    imageWidth: '',
    imageHeight: '',
  },
  onAccept: handleButtonClick,
  },   
};

  return (
    <ConfigCustomImageButton configuration= 
    {buttomConfiguration}/>
  );
};

export default CustomImageButton;
```

Next, I use a file called ConfigCustomImageButton.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import useStyles, { ButtonStylesProps } from 
'./ConfigCustomImageButtonStyles';
import clsx from 'clsx';

type SvgProps = {
  xmlns: string;
  fill: string;
  viewBox: string;
  path: string;
};

type ButtonProps = {
  buttonText?: string;
  showText?: boolean;
  imageSvg?: string;
  showImage?: boolean,
  imagePosition?: "left" | "right";
  customStyles?: ButtonStylesProps; // Allow for custom styling
  svgData?: SvgProps;
  onAccept: () => void;
};

interface PropsInterface {
  configuration: {
    buttonProps: ButtonProps;
  };
}

// Default values for various properties
const defaultProps: ButtonProps = {
  buttonText: "Button",
  showText: true,
  imageSvg: "no src",
  showImage: true,
  imagePosition: "left",
  svgData: {
    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    fill: "currentColor",
    viewBox: "0 0 16 16",
    path: "M6.95.435c.58-.58 1.52-.58 2.1 0l6.515 
    6.516c.58.58.58 1.519 0 2.098L9.05 15.565c-.58.58-1.519.58- 
    2.098 0L.435 9.05a1.482 1.482 0 0 1 0-2.098L6.95.435Zm1.385 
    6.547.8 1.386a.25.25 0 0 0 .451-.039l1.06-2.882a.25.25 0 0 
    0-.192-.333l-3.026-.523a.25.25 0 0 0-.26.371l.667 
    1.154-.621.373A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 6 8.632V11h1V8.632a1.5 1.5 0 0 
    1 .728-1.286l.607-.364Z",
  },
  customStyles: {
    titleColor: '',
    titleFont: '',
    colorButton: '',
    borderRadius: '',
    imageHover: '',
    imageWidth: '',
    imageHeight: '',
  },
  onAccept: () => {},
}; 

const ConfigCustomImageButton = ({ configuration }: 
PropsInterface) => {
  const { buttonProps } = configuration;

  const classes = useStyles(buttonProps.customStyles || {});

  const props = { ...defaultProps, ...buttonProps };

  // Determine the image position class based on imagePosition
  const imagePositionClass =
    props.imagePosition === "right" ? classes.imagePositionRight 
    : classes.imagePositionLeft;

  // Conditionally render elements based on props
  const showText = props.showText && <h3 className= 
    {clsx(classes.text, classes.customText)}>{props.buttonText} 
    </h3>;

  const svgData = props.svgData || defaultProps.svgData; 
  const svgContent = (
    <svg className={clsx(classes.imageSVG, 
    classes.customImage)} xmlns={svgData?.xmlns} fill= 
    {svgData?.fill} viewBox={svgData?.viewBox}>
      <path d={svgData?.path} />
    </svg>
    );
  const showImage = props.showImage && svgContent;

  return (
    <button className={clsx(classes.button, 
    classes.customButton)} onClick={props.onAccept}>
      <div className={clsx(classes.divButton, 
      imagePositionClass)}>
        {showText}
        {showImage}
      </div>
    </button>
  );
}
export default ConfigCustomImageButton;
```

Finally, here's the CSS file called ConfigCustomImageButtonStyles.tsx:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export interface ButtonStylesProps {
  titleColor?: string;
  titleFont?: string;
  borderRadius?: string;
  colorButton?: string;
  imageHover?: string;
  imageWidth?: string;
  imageHeight?: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  text: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 400,
    transition: ".3s ease all",
    margin: '0.5rem',
  },

  divButton: {
    display: "flex",
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  imageSVG: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: '0.2rem',
    width: '25px',
    height: '25px',
  },

  imagePositionRight: {
    justifyContent: "start",
  },

  imagePositionLeft: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  },

  button: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    color: "#fff",
    border: "none",
    background: "#9b5ca8",
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 500,
    transition: ".3s ease all",

    "&:hover": {
      background: "#b04b93",
    },
  },

  //Custom Styles
  customText: (props: ButtonStylesProps) => ({
    color: props.titleColor || 'white',
    fontFamily: props.titleFont || 'inherit',
  }),

  customButton: (props: ButtonStylesProps) => ({
    background: props.colorButton || '9b5ca8',
    border: props.borderRadius || 'inherit',
    "&:hover": {
      background: props.imageHover || "#b04b93",
    },
  }),

  customImage: (props: ButtonStylesProps) => ({
    width: props.imageWidth || '25px',
    height: props.imageHeight || '25px',
  }),
}));

export default useStyles;
```

I have already tried using hooks like useState and useEffect for the initial render, useMemo and useRef, as well as various configurations for useStyles.

I hope you can help me because I can't understand why this is happening, and it has never happened to me before.

Codemized.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If want people's help, you have to make it easy for them, so [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please [edit] your question and add in the code the code that's giving you trouble. Using the formatting tools to put that code in code tags so that it can be easily read by answerers.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and placed the code instead of images. Thank you very much!